# Show that the integral of a continuous function is surjective

Tags: calculus

I am struggling to solve the following problem.
I would appreciate some guidance.

Problem:

Let $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be continuous and bounded below by a positive number $m.$
Fix $b$ (a constant) in $\mathbb{R}$ and define $F(x) = \int_b^x f(t)\,dt$.
Prove that $F:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is a bijection.

I have managed to show that $F$ is increasing, continuous and injective.
However, I have not yet managed to show that it is surjective.
How could I do this, please?

Comment: Thank you, user7530 for editing my question.  How may I learn the way to typeset mathematics?  Where may I learn  commands such as the ones you used in my post?

Comment: There is this [MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 3):

**Detailed Hint:**

The [Mean Value Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem) says that for some $c$ between $b$ and $x$,
$$
\frac{F(x)-F(b)}{x-b}=f(c)\ge m\tag{1}
$$
Therefore, for any $y\gt F(b)$,
$$
F\left(b+\frac{y-F(b)}m\right)\ge y\tag{2}
$$
Thus, no matter how big $y$ is, there is an $x$ so that $F(x)\ge y$.

Furthermore, for any $y\lt F(b)$
$$
F\left(b+\frac{y-F(b)}m\right)\le y\tag{3}
$$
Thus, no matter how small $y$ is, there is an $x$ so that $F(x)\le y$.

Since $F$ is the integral of a continuous function, $F$ is continuous. The [Intermediate Value Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem) finishes things off.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $c>b$.

1. Can you prove a lower bound for $F(c)$?
2. For any $y>0$, can you find a $c$ with $F(c) \geq y$?
3. For any $y>0$, can you show there exists a $c$ with $F(c) = y$?

And then the negative case follows from an identical argument.